# Show latest commit for a user across all branches

Tags: git, git-log

I tried to get the latest commit for a user using this command

```
git log --author=Jon
```

The returns a list of commits but they seem only to include commits made on this branch (incl. merges etc.)

How can I search across all branches for the latest commit of a particular user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add the `--all` flag for that.

It will take every existing branch tip as candidate for the search.

([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---all))